# Finding all views/namespace urls in a Zope3 system?

Tags: python, linux, plone, zope, centos6.5

I have a Zope3 system with some custom code for a paperless office system.  The developers have since folded up shop and I need to make some changes to what I believe are the contents of some ExtJS.ComboBox pulldowns.

Once upon a time the developers told me to hit a certain URL on the server to refresh the combo box data, but I've got no documentation what the URL was anywhere.

Is there a way to query ZODB or Zope to spit out a list of known URLS in the system?  I want to say it was localhost:8080/++etc++site/@@something .. it was a very odd looking URL from my recollection.

The usual urls such as http://localhost:80(80)/Contol_Panel or /@@manage don't get me to what some of the ZMI documentation suggests I should get. I am unsure as to whether this was intentional or not.

Comment: Those `@@` meant that `@@something` is a View: some Python code that will do some computing over the resource from that path. You won't find `@@something` in ZODB. More info: https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html

Comment: @ThiagoCurvelo but wouldn’t there be a way to programmatically identify all namespaces and views in the system ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a addon called [collective.z3cinspector](https://pypi.org/project/collective.z3cinspector/)

You might use version 1.1 for Python 2.7 / Plone < 5.2 or version 1.2.1 for Python 3 compatibility.

Navigate to http://localhost/@@inspect to inspect all registered adapters and utilities (singleton adapters)

[image]

In case of `/++etc++site/@@something` you can search for an adapter named `etc`. You will see something similar to what you can see in the image.